# Redirection after authentication fandjango

Tags: django, redirect, fandjango

I just now started using fandjango and the `FANDJANGO_SITE_URL` in my settings.py is `mydomain.com`. But after I call

```
@facebook_authentication_required
```

The app asks me for permission, and after that the URL is somewhat like:

```
mydomain.com/fblogin?code=somecode
```

But the view for which the decorator was executed did not execute. How do I make the app execute the same view for which it was called? Or how do I parse this URL and call another view if the former is not possible?

Comment: Just wondering did you mean to use authentication instead of authorization? I.E. all the docs point to @facebook_authorization_required

Comment: @Jeff_Hd: Ya thats what I mean. It asks the user for app permissions. Am asking about the redirection after the permissions are given

Comment: Based on the decorator cxode here: https://github.com/jgorset/fandjango/blob/master/fandjango/decorators.py I have a feeling you should be using `FACEBOOK_AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URL`

Comment: @Jeff_Hd: Adding that doesnt change any